# How should i create an object with dinamic variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wanted to create a signature object, always the flag is being false, it should be true or false

i was reading the doc https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/main/GETTING_STARTED.md#traits

```
let!(:signature) { FactoryBot.create(:signature, flag: true) }
let!(:signature) { FactoryBot.create(:signature, flag: false) }
```

this is the factory:

```
factory :signature do
    flag {}
  end
```

Comment: What is even your question here? Any options you pass to `create/build_stubbed` will override the properties you define in your factory. Defining a default for a boolean should be done in your database schema definition.

Comment: Traits are used to group a set of values together so that you can mix them into other factories. Its not really relevant to whatever this is.

Answer (score -1):

To make the default flag attribute false:

```html
factory :signature do
  flag false
end
```

Then you would do something like:

```html
let!(:default_flag_signature) { FactoryBot.create(:signature) } // flag will be false
let!(:true_flag_signature) { FactoryBot.create(:signature, flag: true) } // flag will be true
```

Comment: does not worked, i tried with your code

Comment: You should not have to define a default for a boolean column in your factory and doing so actually just masks over an anti-pattern called *tri-state booleans*. Instead you should make the column non-nullable and add a default in the database.